# PayPal Sandbox Blank Address Error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I just recently started working with the PayPal API to start processing credit cards for a client and have run into an odd issue. I managed to get everything mostly working (the 400 Bad Request error that is all over SO is still outstanding for me) minus one thing. When I try to run a CC against the sandbox area with nothing specified for line 2 of the address I see the following error get logged:

Error Response: {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.billing_address.line2","issue":"Must not be blank"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"cbaa2c4dfdb77"}

Why would address 2 be required? Their own documentation (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) says it isn't so I'm completely lost here.

This is using the RestAPISDK library downloaded from their GitHub instance and everything I'm doing is in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a blank value in a REST API call it will return an error. It isn't required to provide a `line2` value but if you include the variable with a blank value the system will flip out. Remove the variable entirely and you should be good to go.